# Repair grub on Ubuntu Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I've got Ubuntu 12.04.1 running as a Virtualbox on Windows 7.  Ubuntu crashed (it claimed the host had too little memory, but this seems a bit odd as I have 6 Gb of ram and was only giving Ubuntu 2 Gb), so I restarted Ubuntu.  However, when I did this, I got the following error:

```
error: ELF header smaller than expected
grub rescue>
```

I initially tried the solution provided at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599293 - but couldn't find the location of the iso in Step 4 (presumably because it's a VirtualBox anyway?)

When I boot from the iso, I don't get an option to repair, only boot from CD or install from scratch.

Is there a way to either:

- boot Ubuntu from the iso and then repair the appropriate files by mounting the harddrive

or

- install a fresh version of Ubuntu, and mount my 'old' harddrive to it so that I can recover the files

Is either option possible / better than the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd.html works perfectly, with very clear instructions!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Would you please update the answer by outlining the steps one by one as this link is no longer working?

Comment: Link works now and redirects to a phishing site...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the ISO is mounted on the VM; if it is, then it should appear in the results when you do 'ls' at the grub rescue prompt, and you should be able to continue with step 4 as normal.

That said, it may be simpler just to rebuild the VM from a fresh Ubuntu install, and recover your files from there. If you go that route, I'd suggest cloning a safe copy the new VM as soon as you've finished the stock Ubuntu install, or else right before you recover your data; that way, if the VM crashes and dies again, you can just clone the safe copy and start from there, rather than having to rebuild from scratch again.

Comment: Hmm, the bad news is that I have mounted the iso, and it still doesn't appear anywhere logical (I've tried all the folders that appear in ls (hd0,msdos1)/